# Personal Veterinary Questions

Tags: discussion

I touched on this opinion [before](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/clarifying-our-scope-with-regards-to-medical-questions/613#613), but with the advent of [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21505/is-it-possible-to-resurrect-dead-animal-by-using-its-dna) I want to give the idea it's own forum.

Are personal veterinary questions on topic?

I want to say no, even if the patient in question is already dead, based on the exact same reasons outlined in my previous answer.

### EDIT:

As Terdon pointed out, maybe that question is not a personal veterinary question. I don't think the OP was asking about cloning specifically, which is why I thought it might fall into this category.  Questions about resurrecting tissue might be off topic for other reasons as well.

More questions that are boarder line:

I think these are Ok:

[Maintaining purebred pedigrees and how to lessen chance of getting disease?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14966/maintaining-purebred-pedigrees-and-how-to-lessen-chance-of-getting-disease)

[Can pets catch the cold?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14057/can-pets-catch-the-cold)

I think this one probably isn't:

[Raphide toxicity in Pothos plant](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9580/raphide-toxicity-in-pothos-plant)

I'm also not sure the transfer to Pets Beta.  I think it will work some of the time, but I think the Raphide question would probably be off topic there as well.  If someone was asking a veterinary question about lab animals I think it should also be off topic.  Ie:

How many times can I inject LPS in a rhesus macaque before it's a problem?

My mice showed up from the vendor hunched over and with ruffled fur.  I've ruled out A, B, and C, what else could be the problem. Or what can I do to help them recover.

Comment: That particular question is not really about veterinary science but about cloning. The answer would be that even if the OP were to clone his pet, he would get a completely different individual albeit with more or less the same DNA. I'm just pointing this out because I think you raise a good point and you might want to find a better example.

Comment: @terdon Updated the question accordingly, but I'm not so sure that was a cloning question.  I think OP was wondering if he/she gathered up all the pieces of corpse from the pet, if it could be brought back to life.  I think a modern biologist would look at that and have knee jerk thoughts about cloning, but I think that's just how we're prone to read the question.  Anyway, found another example I didn't feel good about pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As 'veterinary' signifies animals, not people, I'd suggest migrating these questions to [**Pets** beta](https://pets.stackexchange.com/). See their [Help Center](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help):

> At a high level, this site is about pets and by that we mean an animal companion that is cared for in a domestic setting and not livestock, wildlife, and pests in and around your home. To that end, questions about items commonly associated with the care and housing of pets are on topic, provided that they don't fall into the types of questions that [aren't a good fit for our model](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
>
> Emergency medical situations [may be accepted](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/798/should-medical-emergencies-always-be-off-topic) on this site provided one or more of these conditions may be met:
>
> 1. There are potential emergency measures that may need to be taken care of prior to bringing to the vet.
> 2. There is no possible way to seek professional veterinary care at this time.
> 3. The situation is, ultimately, preventable and that it is possible to provide some advice on avoiding the situation in the future.

And I agree, these questions aren't the best fit for Biology, I would say they are off-topic, for the same reasons as [personal medical questions are](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).