# Why was it hidden / deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Biology Stack Exchange post: [What could it be? HPV?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90706/what-could-it-be-hpv)

Hi.
My question was hidden / deleted without any attempt to improve the question.
Please can you help me understand or solve the problem?

- On-topic?
If I understand this correctly, then my question is not in violation of the rules and is on-topic.
https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
- Dont-ask?
My question does not fit in with the questions that I should not ask.
https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
- Good answer?
I tried to ask a really good question
https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 6):

This is not and never will be a site for medical diagnosis.

Questions must stand on their own - references to literature and other sources are encouraged, but if someone needs to watch an external video to understand your question that is not acceptable.

This is a Q&A site, not a site for discussion.

Comment: "if someone needs to watch an external video to understand your question that is not acceptable." - For what reason?
The video can capture what I'm asking, it wouldn't be possible to describe it with text.
Why has the question not been adjusted to be acceptable?

Comment: @Ogi22 There are two other points in this answer that you have ignored in your comment. If you can somehow fix your question such that all three are addressed without introducing any other problems, feel free to flag it and a moderator can review to undelete. I do not see any probable path to this outcome.

Comment: @Ogi22 you can convert your video to a gif using gifs.com. See [here](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/turn-youtube-video-gif/) for instructions. Then upload the gif as an image on stack exchange. (However, SE only allows images up to 2 mb, so if your resulting gif is too large, you can copy the resulting gif url from gifs.com and edit using ezgif.com. Ezgif.com has optimization tools to crop size or reduce video quality to shrink the file size.). Again, upload the resulting gif to SE so there is permanent record of your video on this site. You can link to the original video as well.

Comment: @Ogi22, though, as Bryan mentioned, your post ran afoul of a couple of issues, and regardless of post quality, media inclusion, or question importance, we cannot, should not, and will not address personal medical questions on this site (or even questions that can be construed as such). Personal medical questions should *never* be asked online due to the IMMENSE amount of misinformation on the web. Ask a medical provider (ideally your own doctor) any medical questions. Posting any to our SE site is against our policies and will be closed. This is for your sake as much as ours. Hope this helps!

Comment: Why was it deleted instead of closed?

Comment: @canadianer Extremely low quality, unable to be salvaged given the scope of this site, and borderline spam. You have sufficient reputation to view and improve it if you think it can be done.

Comment: @Bryan Krause ##01. I didn't want medical diagnostics
The problem does not concern me.
This is also stated in the post.
##02. According to the content of your profile,y ou are a healthcare professional who is missing out on customers and financial income if by someone answering on similar questions, but this is just your personal problem, which should not spoil this site.
Such an approach is in direct conflict of interest with “SE”.
##03. I have already explained the use of the video.
Video is an advanced and highly appreciated tool for communication and information transfer. ...

Comment: ... I do not think it is right to block something like this when dealing with questions
I do not see a clear contradiction with the rules.
##04. In the title of my post, there is a clear question on a specific matter and clearly specified in the body of the contribution.
The formulation of a good question is very relative.
A specialist can ask a question differently than an ordinary person.
For a specialist, the question of an ordinary person may be bad, but that doesn't mean it's not a good question. ...

Comment: ... ##05. The question to which someone has exerted effort should not simply be erased without the possibility of improvement, not at all for an hour after it was asked.

Comment: @Ogi22 It doesn't matter how many times you say a question asking for a medical diagnosis is not asking for medical diagnosis. I can hold an apple in my hand and no matter how many times I call it an orange, it is still an apple. I am not a medical professional, not sure where you got that idea - I am a scientist. The policy I am enforcing here against medical advice questions is neither my policy nor SE's policy, it is the *Biology.SE community* policy. The question is clear, yes, which is why it is so clearly off-topic.

Comment: Is the “Biology.SE community policy” you refer to the prohibition against [“personal medical questions and health advice”](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? To me, this question does not clearly fit into that category.

Comment: @canadianer Yes; we'll have to disagree then.

Comment: That’s not a particularly constructive response. Perhaps you might explain why a question asking for the underlying cause of a medical condition is akin to asking for health advice.

Comment: @canadianer It's asking for a diagnosis ("is this HPV").

Comment: Yes it is. How is that a personal medical question and/or health advice? It seems like we have different understandings of these terms; perhaps it should be made explicit in the rules that questions asking for a diagnosis, regardless of whether or not it is personal, are off-topic (if that is the case).

Comment: @canadianer I think such questions are already clearly off-topic per https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/clarifying-our-scope-with-regards-to-medical-questions - if you'd like to open a meta question suggesting that diagnosis is fine as long as the asker says the code words "this isn't personal" then go ahead, but I will be vehemently opposed to it.

Comment: I don't care whether diagnosis questions are on- or off-topic. I care that the rules of the site are clear and applied fairly. Nowhere in the help section of this site do I see that questions asking for the medical cause of some symptom are off-topic unless they are personal. The most highly upvoted answer to the question you linked to also does not touch on this specific issue and draws the line at questions about treatment and prognosis. I also would not expect a user to search meta and try to parse through the multitude of relevant questions and answers to determine what is on-topic.

Comment: You might be right that this is a personal medical question, but I don't see any objective evidence for that. All I see is a link to some video showing a wart on a thumb. In cases such as this, I think that the community should decide whether the question is personal or not by voting to close. I could even understand if a moderator closed it unilaterally as it would still be subject to community review. Since this question was deleted instead of closing, the number of people who can even see it has been reduced to 20, and the active members in that group I can count on one hand.

Comment: Anyways, that is my opinion and I recognize that it may be the minority one, so I can leave it at that.

Comment: @BryanKrause The rules are clear. https://biology.stackexchange.com/help
My post doesn't violate the rules in any way.
Please undelete my post so the SE page can serve its purpose.

Comment: @BryanKrause HPV is the name for the virus.
Human papiloma virus.
No diagnosis.